# Android - Execute an http post on wifi connection

Tags: android, android-service, android-wifi

I'm working on an app that logins on a public wifi network. I've got the login working by doing a http post to the authentication server.
My next step is making the app do the http post automatically when there's a new wifi connection, checking that we are connected to the correct ssid.
My question is, which is the best way of doing this? Is the best way to create a service and registering to a broadcastreceiver?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have a look at: [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is that i have a broadcastreceiver that listens to `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` intents. In that broadcast receiver you can check what kind of connection is made by polling the `ConnectivityManager`:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean hasWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) != null && cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isAvailable()  && cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected();
```

And then start the service doing the post to the auth server.

Alternatively you could indeed let the service listen to `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` intents and do the wifi check there.